# Run jquery function when click on bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I want to run an ajax function when I click on bootstrap tab.

I have html:

```
  <li><a href="#upotrebljeni" data-toggle="tab">Upotrebljeni resursi</a></li>
```

jquery ajax function:

```
$('a #upotrebljeni').click(function (e) {
var ajdi = '22';
var radnici = 'radnici';
var prvi = '1'; 
    $.ajax({
            url: 'getRMZ.php', // make this url point to the data file
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{id_akt:ajdi, tabela:radnici, prvi:prvi},
            async: false,
        type: 'POST',
            success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            },
        error:function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        }

        });

});
```

and getRMZ.php pdo file:

```
try {
      /* Establish the database connection */
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

     $result = $conn->query("SELECT id_tabele,naziv FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE prvi = :prvi AND id_akt = :id_akt AND tabela = :tabela");
     $result->execute(array(':prvi' => $_POST['prvi'], ':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt'], ':tabela' => $_POST['tabela']));

    $jsonTable = json_encode($result);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo $jsonTable;
```

Now when I click on tab a #upotrebljeni I dont get any action, any error, nothing ... What can be a problem here?

**UPDATE: I via ajax get an error:** "ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':prvi AND id_akt = :id_akt AND tabela = :tabela' at line 1"

Comment: My guess is that the event bind by bootstrap is executing first and returning true somewhere inside it, so your event is not executing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `id="upotrebljeni"` to your anchor:

```
<li><a id="upotrebljeni" href="#upotrebljeni" data-toggle="tab">Upotrebljeni resursi</a></li>
```

since you're using `#` so it'll target element by `id` not `href`.

Also, because `id` is unique, you just need to use:

```
$('#upotrebljeni').click(function (e) {
```

instead of:

```
$('a#upotrebljeni').click(function (e) {
```

Comment: yes but now my php file via ajax retrun; "ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':prvi AND id_akt = :id_akt AND tabela = :tabela' at line 1"

Comment: I don't think you need the space here. Just try to use `prvi=:prvi` instead of `prvi = :prvi`. The same for other parameters

Comment: I also change query to prepar statemnt: $result = $conn->prepare(... now I get this: Object {queryString: "SELECT id_tabele,naziv FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE prvi=:prvi AND id_akt=:id_akt AND tabela=:tabela"}  but hat is this, this is not json from database ...

Answer (score 2):

`<a id="upotrebljeni" href="#upotrebljeni" data-toggle="tab">Upotrebljeni resursi</a>`

Remove the space.

Use

```
$('a#upotrebljeni').click(function (e) {
```

instead of

```
$('a #upotrebljeni').click(function (e) {
    ^
```

The `a #upotrebljeni` selector will look for an element with the ID *inside* an `<a>` tag, while the `a#upotrebljeni` selector looks for an `<a>` element that has the ID.

Comment: @gmaestro - are you loading this link `#upotrebljeni` via ajax in the first place?

Comment: I load like this: $('a#upotrebljeni').click(function (e) {

Comment: @gmaestro - haa! my bad. I didn't even pay attention to your link. You don't have an "ID". You have a href. You should have an id with "upotrebljeni".

Comment: ok, but now my php file return - via ajax: "ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':prvi AND id_akt = :id_akt AND tabela = :tabela' at line 1"

Comment: @gmaestro - now thats a different error. You're able to get the click to work. You have to work on your SQL syntax I guess & I'm no SQL expert.